# How to pan google-map-react when there's no space for a popover to be displayed

Tags: reactjs, panning, google-map-react

I'm using google-map-react to show some markers on the map and when the user clicks on the marker some information is displayed in a custom popover made with Reactstrap. But the issue is when the market is near the edge of the map the popover is displayed outside of the map. Is there any way to pan the map automatically when there's no space for the popover? Thanks.
[You can check the attached gif for proper understandings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FW9C.gif)